# Hausdorff distance: why can we restrict the range of supremum?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

According to [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) in Wikipedia,
$$
 \sup_{w\in M}\rvert \inf_{x\in X}d(w,x)-\inf_{y\in Y}d(w,y)\lvert
=\sup_{w\in X\cup Y}\rvert \inf_{x\in X}d(w,x)-\inf_{y\in Y}d(w,y)\lvert
$$
is true. I tried to prove it and thought about a special case that $X$ and $Y$ is compact. Then, there exist $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ such that
$\inf_{x\in X}d(w,x)=d(w,x_0),\inf_{y\in Y}d(w,y)=d(w,y_0)$.
I got
\begin{align*}
 \inf_{x\in X}d(w,x)-\inf_{y\in Y}d(w,y)
  &=d(w,x_0)-d(w,y_0)\\
  &\le d(x_0,y_0).
\end{align*}
I do not know whether this strategy is right.
Please give me its proof or hint.

By the way, I succeeded in proving below:
$$
  \sup_{w\in X\cup Y}\rvert \inf_{x\in X}d(w,x)-\inf_{y\in Y}d(w,y)\rvert
  =\max\{\max_{w\in Y}d(X,y),\max_{w\in X}d(x,Y)\}.
$$
Here, $X$ and $Y$ are compact.

Comment: The page also gives the reference in a note $[1]$. Have you checked that?

Comment: As can be seen from the first definition in that Wikipedia article, the Hausdorff distance doesn't depend on the ambient space $M$. Since $X\cup Y$ does contain $X$ and $Y$ you can look at the situation in $M'=X\cup Y$ instead of all of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the triangular inequality in disguise. Writing $d(w,X)=\inf_{x\in X} d(w,x)$ it suffices to show (I let you figure out why) that for every fixed $w\in M$ we have:
$$ d(w,X)-d(w,Y) \leq \sup_{y\in Y} d(y,X).$$

To see this let $\epsilon>0$ and pick $y_0\in Y$ so that $d(w,y_0)\leq d(w,Y)+\epsilon$. Then
\begin{align}
   d(w,X)-d(w,Y) &\leq \inf_{x\in X} d(w,x)-d(w,y_0)+\epsilon \\
                &\leq \inf_{x\in X} d(x,y_0) + \epsilon \\
                &=d(y_0,X) + \epsilon\\
                &\le\sup_{y\in Y}d(y,X) + \epsilon.
\end{align}
And $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I completed the proof. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. And thanks for correcting my misprints.